# Use channels to write byte slice to file can't open file correctly

Tags: file, go, udp

**Hi, I am use udp protocol(must use it) to transfer file,   I encountered a problem when receive byte stream and write to file.**
 As shown below:

```
  type FileInfo struct {  
      Flen int64  
      Fname [24]byte
  }  
  type Datapackage struct {  
       NContent [1000]byte  
       Finfo    FileInfo  
       Datatype  byte  
       NContentLen int64
  }
  func main(){

  var dp Datapackage
  var recvChan = make(chan []byte)  
  var  buf :=new(bytes.Buffer)  
  p :=make([]byte, 1041) // 1041 is receive package len

  ser, _ := net.ListentenUDP("udp", &addr)
  for {  
      _ ,err := ser.Read(p)  
      buf.Write(p)  
      binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &dp)
      if dp.Datatype =='A'{   
          filenamelen := bytes.IndexByte(dp.Finfo.Fname[:], 0)  
          filename := string(dp.Finfo.Fname[:filenamelen]) 
          fp, err := os.Create(filename)
          if  err != nil {  
               fmt.Println(err)
          }  
          go func(fp *os.File){  
             for {  
                 wn, err := fp.Write(<-recvChan)
                 if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)  
                 }
                 if wn < 1000{
                    fmt.Println(wn)
                    break
                 }
             }(fp)
             close(recvChan)
             fp.Close()
          }

      } else{
          recvChan<-dp.NContent[:dp.NContentLen] 
      }

     // }else{
     //      wn, err = fp.Write(dp.NContent[:dp.NContentLen])  
     //      if  err != nil { 
     //          fmt.Println(err)
     //      }
     //     if wn < 1000{  
     //            fp.Close()
     //           continue
     //     }
     //}


  }  
}
```

now as above , there has two method to write data stream to file , one is  usual way that has been Annotations， other is use channels．　　but when use channels , get the size of file is rigth ,but can not  open (eg  exe ,zip )correct ,and if not use channels , the file can open correct , I don't know why?
  any help will appreciated.

Comment: change `go func()` to `go func(fp *os.File)`, then pass `fp`.

Comment: thanks  , I have change ,  still can receive right size of file ,the byte number of file isn't miss  , but can't open correct .

Comment: @Long: Make this work correctly without goroutines and channels first. You're ignoring the bytes read value, so you're trying to write the entire buffer every time. You launch a new writer goroutine on every packet received, so you have an ever growing list of concurrent writers. You never set the `databyte` value. You send a slice over the channel, then you concurrently write to that slice while it's being read into the file -- run this with the race detector. There's probably no reason to use a goroutine here at all, just use a `bufio.Writer` to write to the file.

Comment: @JimB: thank you for your answer sincerely,  may be my code not clear , so I edit again,  I want use udp to receive multiple file, only when datatype is 'A' , create filename and create goroutines, Other times，the receive datatype is 'D' and write slice to chan, if i just test one file ,  work correctly without goroutines and channels, but can't open file  when  file is write over with  chan, although get correct file size at last .

Comment: @Long; like I said, you have a data race when reading and writing the slice. You can't send a slice over the channel and then read into the same slice while your writing. You could copy the slice, or in reality you probably don't need the channel and goroutine at all.

Comment: @JimB: I have test, there is data race between `recvChan<-dp.NContent[:dp.NContentLen]` and  `wn, err := fp.Write(<-recvChan)` , at last  I didn't use goroutine and channels and solove this problem , very thx